# Flutter - how can i get the list of ids in the lisviw builder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can i get a value and the id of the holder of the switch from `listview.builder`, i wanted to make a firebase collection which the values will be stored and to make that work i made a container which holds a name and a `switch` and i made a `listview.builder` to list all of the documents so when i press submit `button` it will submit all of the switch values with their ids

here is the `listview.builder`

```
Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: posts.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 3, 8, 3),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Switch(value: null, onChanged: null),
                                    Text(posts[index].data()["fname"])),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
            ),
            RaisedButton.icon(
              label: Text('Submit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the current states of the switches outside of the build method with a map. Use the post.data()["fname"] as the key

```
var switchStates = {};
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (var post in posts) {
      switchStates[post.data()["fname"]] = false;
    }
  }

  void onSwitchChanged(var key, var newValue)
  {
    switchStates[key] = newValue;
  }
```

And then on the listView

```
 Switch(value: null, onChanged: (value) => onSwitchChanged(posts[index].data()["fname"], value);)
```

Finally you can access to the ids and values with the switchStates map.

```
var keys = switchStates.keys;
var values = switchStates.values; //Use them in onPressed
```

Comment: `Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null`
i am getting this error on the switch

Comment: and how can i set the data with key as the field and the value as the value in firestore

Comment: Switch(value: false, onChanged: (value) => onSwitchChanged(posts[index].data()["fname"], value);)

Comment: when i make it false the value cant be changed at all

Comment: You're right. Define a bool variable outside of the builder and pass it to value:. Remember to update its value on the onChanged method (switchVar = newValue)

Comment: *inside of the item builder but before the return

Comment: when i do that all of the switches change together

Comment: You already initialized them in the switchStates map. So if you do value: switchStates[posts[index].data()["fname"]] it should work.

Comment: thank you so much for this this was so helpfull and i have another question tho [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64603723/flutter-how-can-i-set-field-and-value-from-list) cant you help me with this because i can see you can understand this so well

Comment: Thank you! The question is marked as "Closed" so it doesn't accept new answers.